# Where did Whiterun go?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to Fast Travel back to my house in Whiterun, but the only things near where I think Whiterun is supposed to be are:

> - Whiterun Military Camp
>
>   Whiterun Stormcloak Camp
>
>   Honningbrew Meadery
>
>   White River Watch

Am I in need of a geography lesson, or is Whiterun just not available at this point in the game?  If the latter, will it become available again later?

I hesitate to visit either of the first two locations above, because I don't want to chance triggering a possible storyline development that I might not want to deal with just yet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sounds like you're in the middle of the Civil War Questline. This is a perfectly normal thing when it  happens during the Civil War's Battle for Whiterun.

After the battle is concluded, it'll return to normal (and reappear on your map).

For future reference, this happens to both Solitude and Windhelm also (when you're on the appropriate Civil War quests).

Comment: So, I take it the city is entirely unavailable until after the battle?  Or, is it just not on the map?

Comment: @Iszi - The battle takes place within a specialized version of Whiterun (barricades are added, all homes and shops locked and unenterable) that only exists for the quest, and fully replaces the city for the duration of the quest. The city is entirely unavailable until after the battle.

Comment: The city still had the damage but wasn't on fire and I could go back to Jorrvaskr and the inn without picking he lock. I had to leave and return. Everyone treated me exactly the same.